# Cancel running handler

Tags: java, android, handler

Ok, so I'm kinda new to android java programming. I've been searching for an answer for quite some time now without any success.

Here's an example:

```
setAlarmHandler(difference); //(difference is in MS)

public void setAlarmHandler (long difference) {
    Handler myHandler = new Handler();

    Runnable setAlarm = new Runnable() {    
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("test");
        }
    };

    // Schedule the execution
    myHandler.postDelayed(setAlarm, difference);
}

public void addListenerOnCheckBox1() {

    checkBox1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(checkBox1.isChecked()){
                                myHandler.removeCallbacks(setAlarm); }
            }
    });

}
```

So I try to cancel the handler from `"addListenerOnCheckBox1()"` but I get the error `"myHandler cannot be resolved"`. So what do I need to do to be able to cancel the handler from this method? Also, if I just ignore the "cancelling-part" (removes `"myHandler.removeCallbacks(setAlarm);")`, the app runs just perfect in my emulator.

I'm sure the answer I'm looking for will make me feel really stupid, but I just can't make this work on my own..Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: where is `addListenerOnCheckBox1()` called in your code?

Comment: In "protected void onCreate"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Handler myHandler` Declare this as a instance variable.

You have declared and initialized `myHandler` in `setAlarmHandler` which makes it local to that method

```
public void setAlarmHandler (long difference) {
Handler myHandler = new Handler();// local to setAlaramHandler
```

Its the same for

```
Runnable setAlarm
```

Comment: Yeah, I figured that I'm making it local, but how do I declare it as an intsance variable? Thanks for your reply!

Comment: @user3140030 You just have to declare it outside the method. For example before `onCreate` within the class.

Comment: Oh, _before_ onCreate being the key! I've tried declaring it in the onCreate but that didn't work. Next problem: "myHandler.removeCallbacks (setAlarm);" gives me error: "setAlarm cannot be resolved to a variable". Sorry for being such a pain. And thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @user3140030 your there is no need for methods. Any way specify the problem and i will help fix it.

Comment: (I know i could use "null" instead of "setAlarm" but I'm planning on having more handlers active at once later on, and if a user wants to cancel only one of them, the "null" will cancel all of them, right?)

Comment: @user3140030 you are getting confused.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'll try to be more clear. In my "addListenerOnCheckBox1" I tried putting "myHandler.removeCallbacks (null);. I then launched the application (emulator), started the handler and before the handler timer was finished I checked the checkbox, but the handler wasn't cancelled at all. (I did also put a "System.out.println("removeCallbacks");" just beneath the "removeCallbacks" to make sure the CheckBox-listener worked, which it did.

Comment: @user3140030 i am pretty sure it will work. also you need to cancel in onPause also to be safe

Comment: It does not. The only way I can get it to cancel is with "myHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);". I think this will come back and bite me later on when I implement more timers at once though, when I only want to cancel one of them, I think all will be cancelled..But we'll see! Thank you for all your help! Much appreciated!

Comment: @user3140030 search for how to set alaram rather than timers and handlers. I guess that is what you want. By the way it will work.

Answer (score 1):

you can remove all the `callbacks` associated with your handler passing `null` as parameter. Your mistake is to create a new instance of the Runnable `setAlarm` every time the method is called.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you're talking about. I'm not passing null as paramter?

Comment: @user3140030 may be you want to check the docs http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#removeCallbacks(java.lang.Runnable)